# Postfix/Rejecting mails

Tags: postfix, smtp, email, spam

How do I make Postfix to reject all mails if the client is not authenticated and to sender is @mydomain? Is the an easy way to do this?

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main.cf should contain this line:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, 
 reject_unauth_destination, reject_unlisted_recipient, permit`

But make sure that the "client" is not in the network defined by `mynetworks=`. Otherwise it will bypass the authentication test.